# Using browser console to send ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP quiz page which posts answer data on clicking the answer by a function called answer() via ajax then loads the question and answer contents if the answer is correct by loadQuestion() function also via ajax. Here is a part of my code:

```
<ul class="choices">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="answer(this);"><span id="a0"><?php echo $questionDetail['a'.$answerOrder[0]]; ?></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="answer(this);"><span id="a1"><?php echo $questionDetail['a'.$answerOrder[1]]; ?></span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="countdown"><div class="saniyeLoading" style="display: none;"></div></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="answer(this);"><span id="a2"><?php echo $questionDetail['a'.$answerOrder[2]]; ?></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="answer(this);"><span id="a3"><?php echo $questionDetail['a'.$answerOrder[3]]; ?></span></a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function answer(elm){
    countdown.stop();
    var answer = $(elm).text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/soru",
        data: {act: 'soru', answer: answer},
        success:function (data) {
            if(data == "success"){
                setTimeout(loadQuestion, 300);
            } else {
                location.href = "/yanlis";
            }
        }
    });
}
function loadQuestion() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/",
        data: {act: 'ysoru'},
        success: function (data) {
            try {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#questionDetailQuestion").text(data.questionDetail['question']);
                $("#a0").text(data.questionDetail['a0']);
                $("#a1").text(data.questionDetail['a1']);
                $("#a2").text(data.questionDetail['a2']);
                $("#a3").text(data.questionDetail['a3']);
                $('.saniyeLoading').hide();
                countdown.start();
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

My problem here is that people can manipulate the answer() function by writing a simple for loop in the browser developer console. Something like this:

```
for(i = 1 ; i <= 4; i ++ ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/soru",
            data: {act: 'soru', answer: $('#a' + i).text()},
            success:function (data) {
                if(data == "success"){
                    loadQuestion();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have found a temporary solution by removing `onclick="answer(this);"` and replacing `answer()` function with `$('.choices a').click()`. Then I'm validating if there is a click event in my PHP page by sending the event via my ajax page.

Would there be a better solution to this problem? I've tried tokens but the problem is as I'm loading questions via ajax, I will have to save the token in an hidden input etc, they can get also get the token and send it.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way you can stop user from using console to manipulate your code. I can suggest following:

1. You can put server side limit on number of Ajax requests accepted from single user.
2. Adding captcha code, if you see unusual activity
3. Obfuscate your code and AJAX call format, so it requires more effort from user to analyze code and will stop most of people
4. Use dynamically generated image with answers "radio buttons" located at random locations and submitting back x and y position of user click event and use server-side logic to match  click position with answer option

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  What do you think of my solution? Do you think it can easily be manipulated?

Comment: Yes. jQuery has .trigger() function which allows you to trigger click event programmatically

Comment: You mean something like `for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { $('#a' + i).trigger("click", function(e) { ... }) }`, right? When I use this code in the console, it chooses all the answers and redirects me to the wrong answer page. I don't know why though :)

Comment: Check this https://josephscott.org/archives/2012/07/difference-between-a-human-click-and-a-trigger-click-with-jquery/

Comment: Just tried with the help of your link, there is a variable named isTrigger which only fires with trigger() function. I think this will fix my problem. Unless if this can also be set to null in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions on the server-side to track each user's correct and incorrect guesses, and enforce the rules.

As long as you rely on the client side to "play nice", you're exposing your application to the will of the end user.

Comment: Actually my application is a quiz in which you cannot go until the end if you answer wrongly. There are 500+ questions. I'm already tracking the answered questions in a session so sadly that's not a solution for me

Comment: Hmm... I'd make the API wholly dependent on user state, which would only be stored on the server. For example; the API responsible for checking if an answer is correct, also has the power to terminate a user's session immediately if it is wrong, requiring them to start over before any more "correct answer" data will be served to them -- this would prevent the exact type of abuse you're trying to avoid.

Comment: The simplest implementation would return data=='failed' even for the correct answer, if the user making the request has "failed" in their session data (from a previous bad answer). Then whatever action restarts their game (hitting /yanlis I believe) would flush their session. This way the game cannot be brute-forced. As long as you're checking that a user in on the question that they're submitting answers for. Again, if the user session data doesn't show they are on this question, then never issue a success response for it.